# Output pandas grouped dataframe without aggregation

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

Suppose I have a pandas DF with 'A','B','C' as column name

```
A    B   C 
a1  b11 c11
a1  b12 c12
a2  b21 c21
a2  b22 c22
```

I can group by 'A', but can I get

```
A  B  C
a1 [b11,b12], [c11,c12]
a2 [b21,b22], [c21,c22]
```

without any aggregation? Hopefully the order (b11 before b12) is kept as occured in the original table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to do exactly what you want, but perhaps this is close enough:

```
In [23]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['a1', 'a1', 'a2', 'a2'],
                            'B' : ['b11', 'b12', 'b21', 'b22'],
                            'C' : ['c11', 'c12', 'c21', 'c22']})

In [24]: grpA  = df.groupby('A')
In [25]: a1 = grpA.get_group('a1')
```

Using that I then get:

```
In [26]: a1['B']  # or a1.B
Out[26]: 
0    b11
1    b12
Name: B
```

also:

```
In [39]: import numpy as np

In [40]: np.array(a1.B)
Out[40]: array([b11, b12], dtype=object)
```

and finally:

```
In [41]: grpdA.get_group('a1').B.tolist()  # leave off `.tolist()` to get a series
Out[41]: ['b11', 'b12']
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

```
In [46]: df.groupby('A').agg(lambda g: dict([(k,g[k].tolist()) for k in g]))
Out[46]: 
                 B               C
A                                 
a1  ['b11', 'b12']  ['c11', 'c12']
a2  ['b21', 'b22']  ['c21', 'c22']
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works or give a link about `agg`? Pandas documentation says that `agg` can accept a function as argument, but it does not say what such function receives and what should return (from your answer I understand a `dict`, but what about its structure?).